60's or 70's Movie about sailors that are saved by people from atlantis
Very much in the style of 20,000 leagues Under the Sea, and Journey to the Center of the Earth. In the movie I remember the sailors are taken to an underwater city where they partake in water games and generally have a very good time, but at the end of the movie they return to the surface and are rescued but decide among themselves not to reveal what they've discovered. Also, one sailor throws a golden treasure he had stolen back into the ocean so not evidence is left.

Sounds like Captain Nemo and the Underwater City - but it is too long ago that I saw the film to be sure.

After some looking I've concluded that was indeed it. thanks

It sounds like Captain Nemo and the Underwater City 
You can see a trailer at Youtube
